# Is there any way to translate words in Safari on iOS and Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, safari, dictionary, language

I am currently reading a few websites in European languages (Spanish, Italian, German and French), and I'd like to be able to quickly translate words that I don't know (not the entire articles, which is why I don't want to use Chrome's translation). I know there's a "define" feature, and it is nice, but it only gives definitions in the same languages as the word of interest, so it is not exactly useful for someone unfamiliar with the language.

So, maybe someone knows a feature or an extension similar to the "define" one, but that would allow me to quickly look up a translation for a word? I'm interested in solutions for both Mac OS X and iOS (latest versions). Maybe there are third-party Italian-, German-, and French-English dictionaries for Apple's "Dictionary" application?

Comment: I'm pretty sure iOS does include a Spanish/English translation dictionary.  But it's not yet possible to add dictionaries without jailbreaking.  There was once an app (Dictionary Append) which was supposed to do this, but it disappeared.

Comment: Safari has its own (Bing) website translation feature.  http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-translate-websites-in-safari-on-ios-8/

Comment: @TomGewecke, thank you! I've heard about the Bing translation feature, but I'd prefer to be able to translate single words, which is what the "define" feature does :) Apparently, we'll have to wait until Apple provides us with more dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OS X you can add 3rd party dictionaries.  See

http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2013/01/adding-dictionaries-to-dictionaryapp.html

Unfortunately it's not possible for iOS yet as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of iOS 14 and macOS Big Sur, this is a feature available now built into Safari. A translation icon will appear in the address bar when on a page that can be translated.

Documentation: https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/translate-a-webpage-beta-ibrw646b2ca2/mac

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Translator App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-translator/id1018949559) includes an extension for Safari to select text in a web page and translate it (according to its [FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/help/ios/)).